# Adding suffix to table headers - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there a faster way to add to the table headers the suffix "__patients" than just changing them manually using T.Properties.VariableNames?

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;

load patients
T = table(Gender,Smoker,Height,Weight);
T.Properties.VariableNames = {'Gender_patients' 'Age_patients' 'Height_patients' 'Weight_patients'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a loop, which is a bit less manual:

Set up a (shorter) table

```
T = table(1,2,3,4);
T.Properties.VariableNames={'A','B','C','D'}

T =

  1×4 table

    A    B    C    D
    _    _    _    _

    1    2    3    4
```

Now the loop:

```
for k = 1:numel(T.Properties.VariableNames)
    T.Properties.VariableNames{k} = sprintf('%s_patients', T.Properties.VariableNames{k});
end
```

Result

```
T =

  1×4 table

    A_patients    B_patients    C_patients    D_patients
    __________    __________    __________    __________

        1             2             3             4
```